# Assert list of list equality without order in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the best way to assert two lists of lists are equal without importance of order? e.g. these two lists are equal:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
b = [[4,3], [2,1]]

assert lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # True
```

How can `lists_equal_without_order` be implemented, ideally with using some of Python's existing assertions?

Comment: I thought you were a student asking for homework help until I saw your rep. ;)

Comment: I assume you still want to allow duplicates (no so `set`ting the outer list) and we may not assume hashability of the elements nor a natural sorting order?

Comment: Are the sublists always 2 in size, equal size or variable size?

Comment: @KitSunde ;) in my case sublists are of size 2, but a general approach would be nice.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I don't care about duplicates in my case, but again, would be nice if the solution took those into account. Elements are always integers in my case, so hashability req makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no duplicates in the items in `a` or `b`, then
you could use a set comprehension to collect the frozen set of each item.
For example,

```
In [106]: {(frozenset(item)) for item in a}
Out[106]: {frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({3, 4})}
```

Then test if these sets are equal:

```
In [107]: {(frozenset(item)) for item in a} == {(frozenset(item)) for item in b}
Out[107]: True
```

---

This works because sets have no order, and frozensets are hashable (and therefore can be elements of a set). If there are no duplicates, then frozenset equality makes `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` equivalent:

```
In [109]: frozenset([1,2]) == frozenset([2,1])
Out[109]: True
```

But note that if there are duplicates, then frozensets would make `[1,1,2]` equivalent to `[2,2,1]`:

```
In [108]: frozenset([1,1,2]) == frozenset([1,2,2])
Out[108]: True
```

Answer (score 2):

One version that only works with a bunch of assumptions:

```
def lists_equal_without_order(a, b):
    """
    We don't care about duplicates in list comparison or the sublist comparison.
    * [1,2,2] === [1,1,2]  # True
    * [[1,1], [1,1]] == [[1,1]] # True
    The element lists are either the same length or we don't care about duplicates
    * [1,1,1] === [1]  # True
    """
    for l1 in a:
        check_list = frozenset(l1)
        if not any(check_list.issuperset(l2) for l2 in b):
            return False
    return True

a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
b = [[4,3], [2,1]]

print lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # True

a = [[1,1], [2,2]]
b = [[1,2], [2,1]]

print lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # False
```

One version that messes up the original list:

```
def lists_equal_without_order(a, b):
    """
    This will manipulate the original lists.
    """
    for l1 in a:
        l1.sort()
        for l2 in b:
            l2.sort()
            if l1 == l2:
                b.remove(l2)
                break
        else:
            return False
    return True

a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
b = [[4,3], [2,1]]

print lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # True

a = [[1,1], [2,2]]
b = [[1,2], [2,1]]

print lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # False
```

One version that does an exact match with counters, but doesn't need to keep 2 copies of the lists in memory:

```
from collections import Counter

def lists_equal_without_order(a, b):
    """
    This will make sure the inner list contain the same, 
    but doesn't account for duplicate groups.
    """
    for l1 in a:
        check_counter = Counter(l1)
        if not any(Counter(l2) == check_counter for l2 in b):
            return False
    return True

a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
b = [[4,3], [2,1]]

print lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # True

a = [[1,1], [2,2]]
b = [[1,2], [2,1]]

print lists_equal_without_order(a, b)  # False
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `sorted()` instead of the inplace `.sort()` , I don't think it would be desirable to cause the actual data to change during an assertion.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Absolutely true, what JonClements just posted looks fantastic.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I was a bit bored and added two more solutions. One using frozenset inspired by the other answers, but ignores all levels of duplicates and one using Counter. These don't need to create full copies of the lists to do the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

If there are no duplicates in the sublists (or duplicates can be ignored), this approach works:

```
def lists_equal_without_order(a, b):
    return set_repr(a) == set_repr(b)

def set_repr(x):
    return {frozenset(item) for item in x}
```

---

If we need to account for duplicates within the sublists, we need to use Counters instead of frozensets:

```
from collections import Counter

def lists_equal_without_order(a, b):
    return counter_repr(a) == counter_repr(b)

def counter_repr(x):
    return {frozenset(Counter(item).items()) for item in x}
```

---

If the sublists themselves can occur multiple times (i.e. if the outer list contains duplicates), we can use a Counter for the outer list:

```
from collections import Counter

def lists_equal_without_order(a, b):
    return counter_repr(a) == counter_repr(b)

def counter_repr(x):
    return Counter(frozenset(Counter(item).items()) for item in x)
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a factor, A simple solution would be to first sort the inner lists, and then sort the outer lists, and then compare them.

Example -

```
def lewo(l1, l2):
    l1new = [sorted(i) for i in l1]
    l2new = [sorted(i) for i in l2]
    l1newsorted = sorted(l1new)
    l2newsorted = sorted(l2new)
    return l1newsorted == l2newsorted
```

Or more tersely -

```
def lewo(a, b):
    a_s, b_s = map(sorted, a), map(sorted, b)
    return sorted(a_s) == sorted(b_s)
```

Comment: I like this approach, and I don't see a big performance penalty here.

Answer (score 0):

Well run a loop taking for the size of the list.

A=list a;

B=list b;

For i running from 0:size of loop

{ 
Temp =a[i];

If (temp is there in set B)
    Remove temp from B;

}

If B is empty set Then A=B;

Else 
A!=b

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I'm looking specifically for Python code, and I'm not sure your solution even works.

Answer (score 0):

a different `set/frozenset` approach:

```
a = [[1,2], [3,4]]
b = [[4,3], [2,1]]

def lists_equal_without_order(lst0, lst1):
    set0 = set( frozenset(item) for item in lst0 )
    set1 = set( frozenset(item) for item in lst1 )
    return set0 == set1

print(lists_equal_without_order(a,b))
```

i'm not entirely sure it covers all your use-cases. works for the example you gave though...